# Has Rowling commented on the Goblins' resemblance to the common "Jew" caricature?

Tags: harry-potter, jk-rowling

As a disclaimer, I am *not* asking whether or not Rowling is an antisemite.  She has commented on antisemitism before, and the answer to the question of her deeply held personal views would almost certainly be opinion-based.  I am wondering only whether or not she addressed the specific question about the Goblins of the Harry Potter universe.

Basically, it's this: Rowling's Goblins raise a very understandable red flag for quite a few Jews.  Their faces are essentially dead ringers for the common offensive caricature of a stereotypical "Jew," complete with the long nose, wrinkles, the evil smile, and the long grabbing clawed fingers.  They love money / coins, and hoard gold.  And, rather than just burying or hiding it, they work within the established financial system as bankers, and they wear suits.  In the 21st century it's difficult for this to simply be waved away via visual fairy tale elements, so I am wondering whether or not Rowling has commented on this specific part of the Harry Potter franchise.

Comment: I'm sure I've seen this question before, either on this site or [literature.se], but all my searching isn't finding it ...

Comment: Umm, you’re comparing the movie representation of Goblins or JKR’s description from the books? I’m confused. The question seems to be swinging between the two.

Comment: @Shreedhar I did not mention films or books in the question.  However, I am thinking mainly of the films - in the making of which Rowling was very much involved.

Comment: As a Jew, I want to point out that I do not look like a goblin, in any way, shape, or form. Thank you. (But I do like money.)

Comment: Maybe it is the other way round: these caricatures were (indirectly) based on goblins, leprechauns and other folk lore creatures who like gold coins.

Comment: @TimSparrow Jewish caricatures are based on a grossly exaggerated stereotype of Semitic features as perceived by Europeans, and the association of Jews with gold has mainly to do with historical restrictions placed on jobs available to Jews in Europe. Neither came from goblins. But regardless of that, I'm not really a fan of the naivete argument, especially when it comes to damaging historical imagery (I see it sometimes applied to blackface use - "this has nothing to do with racism, only with the character's skin"). Creative choices matter. Real goblins don't exist. Jewish caricatures do.

Comment: Before commenting, I *will* point out that the only encounters I have ever had with these "Jewish stereotypes" has been people complaining that something else is "based on it".  The Goblins in the Harry Potter films are based on old tales of goblins appearing as small, twisted, greedy and ugly old men, as part of ancient stereotypes of "good = beautiful / evil = ugly".  Goblin-like creatures exist in old Greek, Roman, Chinese and Native American mythology. That anti-Semites **later** coöpted some of these characteristics and rebranded them as "Jewish" stereotypes is a different matter entirely

Comment: @Chronocidal *Anti-Semites later coöpted some of these characteristics and rebranded them as "Jewish" stereotypes* - Can you please cite your source for this?

Comment: @MishaR You mean *beyond* the stereotypes having existed for centuries in cultures that hadn't ever met Jewish people yet?

Comment: @Chronocidal I mean beyond what seems to be a fabricated historical claim. For the second time - can you please cite a source that backs up the claim you are making.

Comment: @MishaR The [Pukwudgie](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pukwudgie) and [Muki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Muki_(mythology)) are both goblin-like short, ugly creatures with distorted features in Native American mythology, who predate the discovery of the Americas by Europeans.  The Muki *in particular* is associated with mining and metals **such as gold**.

Comment: @Chronocidal *Anti-Semites later coöpted some of these characteristics and rebranded them as "Jewish" stereotypes* - I asked you to provide a source backing up this claim. Can you do it or not.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/98803/discussion-between-chronocidal-and-misha-r).

Comment: I would argue that they were based on the common caricature of goblins AND the common caricature of "old timey" bankers then mashed into 1.  The interpretation that they look like pre-wwII era caricatures of jews (and I see what you're saying there) says more about how jews were historically depicted than anything else

Comment: It's also hard to miss the fact that in the Harry Potter series, the goblins are presented as a people who have historically gotten the shaft in a big way for a long time. Whether that is supposed to remind us of the Jewish people is left for others to answer.

Comment: Nifflers also dig for gold, so I have a lot of questions about them too.

Comment: @MishaR - If a folkloric character is demonstrably not based on an anti-Semitic caricature, but it makes people think of an anti-Semitic caricature, I would suggest that the onus is upon me to not be offended by it, in much the same way that towns with names that are obscenities in other languages should not have to accommodate me.

Comment: I think the analogy to blackface is weak because blackface is intrinsically a racial caricature by its definition: someone is assuming a poor imitation of the physical features of another race or ethnicity, although blackface is racist for many other reasons as well. By contrast, if a folkloric character *coincidentally* shares a trait or two with a later racist stereotype, there is about as much reason for offense as if a rock pattern on Mars coincidentally looks like a swastika.

Comment: Or, you know, if a prayer flag in South or Southeast Asia very much non-coincidentally looks like a swastika. Of course, it is possible that the portrayal of goblins in *Harry Potter* is not coincidental and is precisely due to the author drawing upon stereotypes of some group. That would be a separate question.

Comment: @Adamant Your swastika example wouldn't hold water if Rowling inserted a swastika somewhere within Harry Potter.  The swastika is an old image, far older than the Third Reich, but you cannot claim ignorance of its connotations if you choose to use it in the 21st century.  Same with the Goblins as they are portrayed in the movies.  Regardless of what else they *could* be, they are a very close match for a very specific stereotype.  And, since they are fictional, portraying them this way was a choice.  Saying that there is no good reason for this to raise red flags seems disingenuous.

Comment: @MishaR - The goblins in the movies might be. There was a goblin in the *Fantastic Beasts* movie that seemed to play on Jewish stereotypes, at least. However, they are not the same as the ones in the books (not that the books are not problematic in other ways). In the books, all you have is goblins with pointy noses who like gold, which are frankly quite generic folkloric features whose connection with anti-Semitism in this context is quite dubious.

Comment: Also, I am not sure what your argument that "she made a choice" is meant to imply. If it is meant to imply that, if a folkloric character's origin is unrelated to anti-Semitism, portraying them faithfully to their origins is wrong because people with insufficient knowledge of folklore might make assumptions, I cannot agree. If the argument is that it is an indicator that she might be anti-Semitic, perhaps—but if gold-loving goblins with pointy noses are indeed common in folklore for reasons other than anti-Semitism, I quite honestly do not think it is a very strong one.

Comment: It kind of seems to me that you think something along the lines of "as long as people could misinterpret this as anti-Semitic, Rowling is showing that she does not care how they feel, which is probably a sign that she is anti-Semitic." If that is the case, I don't. I am more concerned with eliminating actual anti-Semitism.

Comment: @Adamant I specifically mentioned in the question that I am not asking whether or not she is an antisemite, but only on whether or not she commented on the goblins.  It's the very first thing my question says, in fact.  Yes, I'm mainly talking about the movies, but she had a lot of say over that.  And I don't think that it's much of a stretch to interpret a hook-nosed conniving banker in a suit as a Jewish stereotype.  I think that it's a familiar enough image where choosing to go with something as closely resembling it as the movies' goblins deserves at least a comment.

Comment: @MishaR - I certainly understand people's concerns. At the very least, with the Victorian or medieval aesthetic of the films, the portrayal of their goblins may have drawn on visual symbolism for bankers from those eras—which in turn was influenced by anti-Semitic stereotypes.

Comment: @Adamant I guess I feel like those concerns are understandable enough that they deserve to be addressed in a way that's better than telling people it's their problem if they interpret it that way.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/134226/discussion-between-adamant-and-misha-r).

Answer (score 2):

### Probably Not

One evidence to suggest "no" is that there are many articles online referring to the alleged resemblance between Jews and Rowling's goblin characterization, both [accusational](https://www.nbcnews.com/think/opinion/j-k-rowling-s-harry-potter-goblins-echo-jewish-caricatures-ncna1287043) and [defensive](https://forward.com/culture/480388/please-shut-up-about-the-harry-potter-jew-goblins-antisemitism-jk-rowling/), and none of them seem to make any mention of an official quote from Rowling on the matter.

To further bolster this negative answer, we have the following "unpublished" quote from Rowling taken from a private interview, where the quote has apparently been taken from a transcript shared directly with the author of an essay on [MuggleNet](https://www.mugglenet.com/2019/03/rowlings-goblin-problem/):

> "I’ve never really told the goblin story. It just sort of bubbles under. Because I see them as a really, sort [of] active political force."

If we take this quote as authentic, and assume that there has been no abrogating statement in the years after that 2005 interview (I didn't see anything on Accio Quote), then it seems that she has spoken about goblins only enough to say that she has not really spoken about goblins. Presumably, that includes any relationship to any real world group or ethnicity.